# Weird lines while baking Ambient Oclusion

Tags: rendering, obj, ambient-occlusion

I was baking some AO`s on my pc for some parts for an obj model.
The thing is that, when you finally end the ao bake, some weitrd lines appear in the middle of the piece without the possibility of being removed.
Also they didn´t appear on my ao image, that´s weird.
If someone is wondering for my config, I did not change anything on it, I use the "standard config", I provide some pics of the results below.
[image: AO RESULT]

[image: AO WEIRD LINES]
[image: BAKING SETTINGS]

Comment: First thought.. (not necessarily the fix).. your UV unwrap does look as if it could be cleaner, with less stretch, and clearer separation of islands?  I just think that might give you  an easier starting point, for a diagnosis.